# Redirect requests to different local file but keep url

Tags: php, apache, redirect, proxy

So I have a problem understanding redirects.
Let's say I have
`example.com/id/someuserid`(all after) and if someone makes a request to this url path, I want to execute/redirect them to let's say a handler php file which then gets the incoming Request uri, and showing content based on the user in the url.

I've tried proxy match and apache redirects but they don't seem to be the right thing, or I am just not getting it right

What I've tried is

```
ProxyPass /id/ http://example.com/handler.php
ProxyPassReverse /id/ http://example.com/handler.php
```

Note that the request uri is suppose to be the same and the url should be kept the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule    "^/foo\.html$" "/bar.html" [PT]
```